# How to ensure the quality profile is the default from sonarsource?

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I have access to two different instances of SonarQube.

Admittedly they are running different versions - 6.3.1 and 6.4 respectively (which is out of my hands to update just now).

I'm using the web api to try check the quality profiles used on projects contained in each and make sure they are using the default SonarQube profiles.

Using the API GET call: /api/qualityprofiles/search

I can see the list of quality gates and if they are set as default etc.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to determine if the 'sonar way' profiles are the ones created by SonarQube? I'm assuming someone could come in and create a different profile with the same name and set it as default? I thought the keys would be unique but each instance has completely different keys for each profile....

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked a little further before posting...

You cant delete the Sonar way profile and you cannot create a new profile with the same name...